# Why do continuous random variables have densities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In a basic probability course, there seems to be an implicit assumption that any continuous random variable has a density function, but I don't really see why this should be.  My intuition is that there's some probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ and a measurable function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, and you'd like to know the probability that $X$ takes on a value in some measurable $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  The natural thing to do is look at the push-forward measure, $X_*P(E) = P(X^{-1}(E))$, but in any introductory probability book they make some claim that there's a density function $f$ such that this probability is $\int_E f(x) dx$, which seems to mean $X_*P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, but I don't really see why this should be true in general.

I suppose this should mean that if $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has zero Lebesgue measure, then $X^{-1}(E)$ has has zero $P$-measure, but again I don't see why this needs to be true for an arbitrary measurable function $X$.

Is this just an assumption that introductory books make, or is there something else going on that I'm not seeing?

Comment: A continuous random variable will have a continuous cumulative distribution function.  If the CDF is differentiable then that gives the density, and introductory probability books often assume such behaviour

Comment: Some, more careful, introductory textbooks on probability say that a random variable is called a continuous random variable if it has a cumulative distribution function (CDF) that is (a) continuous everywhere and (b) differentiable everywhere except possibly at a finite set of points. If so, the probability density function is defined to a member of an equivalence class of functions each of which equals the derivative of the CDF (wherever the derivative exists) and are defined to have any positive number values at those points where the derivative of the CDF does not exist.

Comment: @DilipSarwate can you mention that equivalence relation ,whose equivalence class you are talking about

Comment: @MeetPatel The equivalence class is the set of all functions that have value equal to the derivative of the (continuous) CDF everywhere the derivative exists and _arbitrary_ nonnegative values at the finite number of points where the CDF is continuous but not differentiable.  _Any_ ot these (infinitely many) functions can  be used as the pdf of the random variable and it will not make the slightest difference in any calculation which one you these functions you choose as the pdf. That's the equivalence class I am talking about; all the pdfs in the equivalence class give the same results.

Comment: @DilipSarwate So theory goes in this way : Random variable $X$ is said to be continuous  if it's CDF is continuous. now if CDF (say $F_x$) is differentiable on some $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ then for $X$ we define its PDF as function on R which is agree with derivative of CDF on $A$ and any other non-negative values on  rest . is it correct?

Comment: @MeetPatel What you say is nearly true. To make it completely true, $A$ must be restricted to be _all_ of $\mathbb R$ _except_ )possibly) for a finite set of elements of $\mathbb R$ where the CDF is continuous but not differentiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to read the [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) on this. In short, you are right: a continuous distribution need not be absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure (the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) is given as an example in my previous link).

Most of your post is beyond the scope of an introductory course in probability, where most continuous distributions that are studied are ones with densities.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, a "continuous" random variable need not have a density. The actual story is that if $\mu$ is any Borel measure on $\Bbb R$ with $\mu(\Bbb R)=1$ there is a random variable $X$ such that $$P(X\in E)=\mu(E).$$Now $X$ has a density if and only if $\mu$ is "absolutely continuous".

So the actual story gets into measure theory, which is why they can't tell the actual story in an elementary class. Here's a simple "probabilistic" construction of a random variable with no density function:

Say $d_0,d_1,d_2,\dots$ are iid random variables with $P(d_j=0)=P(d_j=2)=1/2$. Let $$X=\sum_{j=0}^\infty d_j3^{-j}.$$

Then $X$ might be described as a random variable "uniformly distributed on the Cantor set". It's  a continuous random variable, in that $P(X=a)=0$ for any fixed number $a$, but it does not have a density function. (The distribution of $X$ is the "Cantor distribution" mentioned in the other answer.) $X$ is an example of the sort of thing they don't want to talk about in the courses you mention.