Existence of a Density Function Given a Continuous CDF
I am teaching a new course on basic probability this year, and one of my students asked an interesting question:
If we know that a cumulative distribution function (CDF) is continuous, is that enough to conclude that there is a corresponding probability density function (PDF)?
Does anyone know the answer to this?
Thank you!

Welcome on MSE! Isn't your question answered here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672968/why-do-continuous-random-variables-have-densities ?

"If $F$ is continuous, it has a derivative, say $f$" is really not true in general.

Yes, you are right, my bad !

It was exactly what I was looking for, thank you !

Classical counterexample: the CDF of the Cantor distribution (which is the Devil's staircase) is continuous, but this distribution has no probability density function. The problem here is that the CDF is continuous but not absolutely continuous!
